# Monitor connected via HDMI does not seem to display FullHD

Tags: resolution, hdmi, external-display

I have a 2nd monitor connected to my laptop (lenovo y700) via HDMI. The resolution of the monitor is 1920x1080 but here`s the problem:
 - if I use extend the picture on the monitor isn't 'crisp' and looks a bit bad
 - but, if I use 'Duplicate displays' it has a great resolution

I am using Win 8.1, my monitor is LG 24MP48HQ

I've been googling like crazy for the past few hours but I can't find anything on the topic. If someone had the same problem and found a solution, I`ll be very greatful!

Comment: Have you tried auto adjust on your screen ? Sometimes it can fix a lot of things. Also, try updating your Video card Drivers.

Comment: I`ve update my drivers, got LG`s windows control tool (no auto adjust on it sadly). I`ve reset the monitor from the menu, still no luck :/

Comment: Uninstalling nVidia card from the Device manager worked the matter out :)

Comment: Please do not forget to answer your own question with a whole procedure on how your solved your problem. It might help few people with a similar problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed with the following steps:

1. Go to Device Manager
2. Find your videocard
3. Right click, uninstall it
4. Restart your computer, it will automatically detect the missing drivers and fetch them from the net (keep the monitor connected)
5. You can install the latest drivers from your card's manufacturer if you wish (I did it)